# Illustrator fill not aligned with path/strokes not smooth

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, stroke, fill

Fill colour doesn't line up with the path on curves in an object.

[image]

Steps:

1. draw line with pen tool
2. apply stroke
3. outline stroke
4. fill and path don't line up

Same thing happens if I create the whole shape (i.e. without first having it as a stroke and outlining it).

Stumped by this one. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Does this happen if you make a new object on a new document? Have you checked to see if there are more paths in the same spot? You might be selecting a path that has no fill and stroke.

Comment: Hey @AndrewH, yup it happens with any custom shape. I've recreated it multiple times on different artboards, new docs, etc. I'm definitely selecting the correct one as I can turn on and off the fill and convert to outlines and see it's the one selected.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this? I'm struggling with the same issue.